# How the read the NINGX PHP FPM Slow Log?

Tags: nginx, php

The log output looks like this. Is the number behind the : the time spent in milliseconds?

```
[26-Sep-2012 23:41:50]  [pool www] pid 17761
script_filename = /srv/bindings/f8d625f884a64f62aea671b2088910cd/code//index.php
[0x0000000001006408] execute() /srv/bindings/f8d625f884a64f62aea671b2088910cd/code/includes/database/database.inc:2139
[0x0000000001005cf0] execute() /srv/bindings/f8d625f884a64f62aea671b2088910cd/code/includes/database/database.inc:664
[0x0000000001005a38] query() /srv/bindings/f8d625f884a64f62aea671b2088910cd/code/includes/database/select.inc:1264
[0x0000000001004760] execute() /srv/bindings/f8d625f884a64f62aea671b2088910cd/code/sites/all/modules/views/plugins/views_plugin_query_default.inc:1398
[0x0000000001003c40] execute() /srv/bindings/f8d625f884a64f62aea671b2088910cd/code/sites/all/modules/views/includes/view.inc:1098
[0x00000000010027f8] execute() /srv/bindings/f8d625f884a64f62aea671b2088910cd/code/sites/all/modules/views/includes/view.inc:1118
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the number behind the : (I guess you mean after)

If so yes:

output query_string and exec_time

http://php-fpm.org/wiki/New_slowlog_format

Answer (score 0):

Nope, is the number of the line of the script on which the function was called.

Example:

execute() /srv/bindings/f8d625f884a64f62aea671b2088910cd/code/includes/database/database.inc:2139

It means that the function execute() was called at line no. 2139 on database.inc file.